# Why does jQuery append() add a left margin/padding to "ajaxed" data?

Tags: jquery, css, append

I have a div that contains tags (like the tags feature on stackoverflow). I use ajax to append new tags to this outer div. Everything works fine, except that there is an additional left margin or padding of about 5px added to newly appended tags. When I inspect the html there is no margin or padding listed, but it is definitely there. The same thing happens in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="tags_wrap">
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="tag_wrap">Tag 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
        <div class="tag_wrap">Tag 2</div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tags_wrap {
    margin:1px 7px 5px 0px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left !important;
}

.tag {
    padding:0;
    margin:4px 7px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #094C7C;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
}

.tag_wrap {
    position:relative;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #1C7ABF;
    border-right: 1px solid #1C7ABF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1C7ABF;
    border-left: 1px solid #1C7ABF;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#addSomeTags').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function() {
        var newTag = $("form#addSomeTags > input[name=tagField]").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'add_tag.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {tag:newTag},
            success: function(data){
                $('.tags_wrap').append(data);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
});
});
```

The `data` returned to `.ajax()` upon successful completion of my php script will look like the other tags:

```
<div class="tag">
    <div class="tag_wrap">Tag 2</div>
</div>
```

There is always this unwanted left margin or padding on newly "ajaxed" tags. If I refresh the page, then this margin is no longer there. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Ajax data does not manipulate style. Check the output and look for nbsps or the like

Comment: I tried to use $.trim(), but the space is still there. I also used PHP trim() on the server side before echoing it back to the client, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this is simply whitespace, and the HTML answer you get starts with additional whitespace characters. When you remove all of them, it should work ([**demo**](https://phihag.de/2013/so/tags/)):

[image: Screenshot of the working demo]

Comment: I've tried removing the whitespace on the server side, and on the jquery side. Nothing works.

Comment: @NancyCollier Most likely, you have a newline after a closing `?>` somewhere in your php files, so `trim` will not help you. Can you post a [complete](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) example of your code? You can also start with the linked demo code - that does what you want, doesn't it? - and then add your changes step by step.

Answer (score 0):

This is an apparently well known problem that occurs when one use display: inline-block:
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

I personally fix this using flexbox:

on the parent:

```
display: flex
```

and if necessary, on the children:

```
flex-shrink: 0
```